# Populate form with file name from mysql database

Tags: mysql, forms, populate

I've created a series of forms for users to add and edit records in a database.  The database includes audio and image file names (the actual files are moved to folders on submit).

My problem is that I can't get the file names to display on the edit forms.  Which means that unless the user uploads the files again, those fields are blanked in the database! I understand the "type='file'" does not take a "value" attribute.  I was able to get around that in my textareas by simply displaying the php variable in the textarea.  I tried that with file names, and they do display, but outside of the input box, which means... see above, blanked fields within the database.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<li>
    <label for=se_ogg">Sound excerpt (upload .ogg file)</label>
    <input id="se_ogg" type = "file"
    name = "se_ogg">' . $row['se_ogg'] . '</input> 
</li>
```

Any ideas?  Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file input field doesn't allow you to define a value for security reasons otherwise you could hide a file field and use it to grab files from unsuspecting peoples computers. If you just want to display the filename of the file just uploaded just display it as formatted text.

Comment: Thanks, I'd heard it was a security issue but didn't know exactly what that issue was.  This is a bit of a problem for me as my users might need to upload a new version of the file.  I'll have to figure out the most logical and least onerous workflow!